# Updating value in specific dataframe cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this specific Dataframe that I am working on:

#### All this works

```
self.Jobs = pd.read_sql(SQL, self.cnxn)
self.Jobs.columns = ['TARGET_TABLE', 'APT_CONFIG', 'JOB', 'INVOCATION', 'SOURCE_QUERY', 'THREAD', 'DATE_OF_DATA']
self.Jobs['DATE_OF_DATA'] = pd.to_datetime(self.Jobs['DATE_OF_DATA'], format('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
self.Jobs['THREAD'] = self.Jobs['THREAD'].fillna(0).astype('int64')
self.Jobs['DONE'] = 0

Table = 'mytarget'
```

#### This is the problem line:

```
self.Jobs.loc[self.Jobs['TARGET_TABLE'] == Table, 'DONE'] == 1
```

The first column in the dataframe is a list of tables.

When I set the variable `Table`, I want to update the dataframe to have the Column `DONE` be updated from 0 to 1 only on the record where the column `TARGET_TABLE` matches `Table`.

However, it is not updating using the "Problem Line".
What am I missing?

What I need.
I need the column `DONE` for the specific row to be changed to a 1.

Thanks

Comment: self.Jobs.loc[self.Jobs['TARGET_TABLE'] == Table] = 'Done'

Comment: let me fix my question.   THank you for the setup...

Comment: I need to update a specific record. I want the value in the column `Done` to be updated where the match exists

Comment: Change the `==` (equality operator) to `=` (assignment operator)

Comment: thanks Henry....now to figure out why it resets all others back to 0 when I update the one record.

Comment: @arcee123 are you sure it's resetting them back to 0? from the code posted it looks like the initial/default value in the `"DONE"` column is 0.

Comment: yes.  when I change `Table` to a new value and run it again...it changes the rest to 0 again.  Guess I have to go back and find out where I"m wrong.

Comment: appreciate the help tho.  At least that line is better....which is what I asked.

Answer (score 0):

You want to **substitute** a value (in this case *1*) to a particular cell of the table.

So instead of the last *==* write just a **single** *=*:

```
self.Jobs.loc[self.Jobs['TARGET_TABLE'] == Table, 'DONE'] = 1
```